# Ruby undefined Method/NoMethodError '*' for nil:NilClass, works until looped

Tags: ruby

My program orders arrays 1 and 2, and iterates to check whether each element in 1 is the sqrt of each element in 2. I've tested the comparison without the loop and it works fine, so I don't *think* that there's an uninitialised variable.

```
def comp(array1, array2)
  order1 = array1.sort
  order2 = array2.sort

  i = 0

  while i < order1.length
    if order1[i] * order1[i] == order2[i]
      i += 1
    else
      false
    end
  end

  order1[i] * order1[i] == order2[i]

end
```

Can you point me in the direction of the issue? I've also not used Math.sqrt because it times out on my interface.

Comment: If you want to know if the square of *every* element of a sorted `array1` equals the element of a sorted `array2` at the same index position, you could write `array1.sort.zip(array2.sort).all? { |n1,n2| n1*n1 == n2 }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i` equals `order1.length`, after your loop, so the last line of your method is basically

```
order1[order1.length] * order1[order1.length] == order2[order1.length]
```

which is (assuming your arrays are the same length):

```
nil * nil == nil
```

which throws an error. Not sure why you need the last line, if you remove it and simply return a counter, your method works as expected if you use a dedicated counter, for the elements which match your condition, instead of using index for that (your index has to be incremented always):

```
def comp(array1, array2)
  order1 = array1.sort
  order2 = array2.sort

  i = 0
  counter = 0

  while i < order1.length
    if order1[i] * order1[i] == order2[i]
      counter += 1
    end

    i += 1
  end

  counter
end
```

In Ruby it is pretty common to use proper enumerators for iterating over collections, so your `while` can be nicely substituted by [Enumerable#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
def comp(array1, array2)
  order1 = array1.sort
  order2 = array2.sort

  counter = 0

  order1.each_with_index do |el, i|
    if el * el == order2[i]
      counter += 1
    end
  end

  counter
end
```

And as the last step, we can also [Array#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-count) how many elements in an array meet a certain condition without needing to specify a local variable, like so:

```
def comp(array1, array2)
  order2 = array2.sort
  array1.sort.each_with_index.count { |el, i| el ** 2 == order2[i] }
end
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's thorough and I'll look into enumerators.
The program's working but I'm getting
"in `comp': undefined method `sort' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"
now, any thoughts there?

Comment: It seems like you're passing `nil` instead of an actual array to your method.